# How to enhance website product pages for SEO (Opencart, Google)

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, bing

I launched a UK wide furniture business, which I can appreciate is a very difficult industry to break into but none the less I have implemented the basics by ensuring I have:

1. Good meta data (titles, description, and keywords - eventhough it is ignored by Google)
2. Adequate H1 and H2 tags
3. Sitemap submission
4. Good quality content trying to keep the keywords within a certain percentage of all the text (~4%?).

This has resulted in being within the top 10 SERP on Google for about 30 different keyword combinations as shown by GWT (Not the best of keywords but still giving me an online presence)

My question is what can I do to further improve my position? Any general advice which I and others can implement to take it to the next level?

Home page: http://www.imbued.co.uk/
sample product page: http://www.imbued.co.uk/sonya-three-sleeper-inc-storage-drawers-white